# How do you reference other project's dll on vscode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I installed asp.net mvc with yo generator and using vs code in Ubuntu linux. It is working great with angular single page App.  But how will I build Business, Data Access dll project, test project with visual studio code and reference from Web Project?

Answer (score 1):

In your project.json file there is the dependencies section. Put your other projects in this section.

In your web project's project.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "Business": 1.0.0-*"
}
...
```

In your Business project's project.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "DataAccess": 1.0.0-*"
}
...
```

I also have a global.json file in the root folder to specify the src and test projects. Example layout of global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

This works for me with the following folder structure:

```
project/
  global.json
  .vscode/
  src/
    web/
    business/
    dataaccess/
  tests/
    ...
```

Comment: I can't launch my root project. Do you have any details setting for launch.json and tasks.json for root project?

Comment: Just update the paths to be something along the lines of "${workspaceRoot}/src/web/..."